# How to select and highlight a column in view-based tableView?

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have set a view-based NSTableView's property **allowsColumnSelection** to YES.The default value is NO.

```
 self.tableView.selectionHighlightStyle = NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleRegular;
 self.tableView.allowsColumnSelection = YES;
```

I want showing blue background effect when I select a column.

[image: blue background at selected column like this]

Comment: Hint: drawSelection

Comment: drawSelection is the method of what? I think it should not be complex, I use cell-based tableview can support the effect I mentioned at picture.  can you tell me more detail. Thx very much. @EI Tomato

Comment: @El Tomato , Do you mean that when **tableViewSelectionDidChange:** invoke I should get select column and redraw it.  correct?

Comment: Apparently the view-based `NSTableView` does not support column selection. Maybe you can give the cells a background color.

Comment: According @Willeke, View-Based NSTableView does not support column selection directly , But I don't  find some property like select-background color, which can be find at UITableView in UIKit framework.

Comment: What is the name of the `UITableView` select-background color property?

Comment: The cell of UITableView can be set selectionStyle property or selectBackgroundView  to custom select appearance.

Comment: `UITableView` doesn't have a `selectBackgroundView` property. Do you mean the `selectedBackgroundView` property of `UITableViewCell`? `selectedBackgroundView` is a view, not a color. The selection background color is handled by `NSTableRowView`. There isn't a `NSTableVolumnView`.